# insert once using check if query exist mysqli

Tags: mysql, sql, database

how to insert only once with insert SQL? says it like this

```
"INSERT INTO table(`id`,`name`,`address`) VALUES ('$id,$name,$address')"
```

"check if exist" only work in creating a new table but does it able to apply to new record?

I can't set address / name to be appear once as 2 or more name could have the same adress.

Comment: set ID as PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT(if its an INT)

Answer (score 2):

You can do multiple things:

- Set `ID` as primary key (if it isn't already), that will prevent duplicate values from being added.
- Set column to `UNIQUE`, thus MySQL will throw an error and prevent duplicates in this column.

Comment: unique means it can't have multiple same record? what if I have to allow it to duplicate base on my table relationship?

Comment: You create a special table for relations where you allow duplicates in a column (for many-to-many relationships)

Comment: I don't get it. I run the query with same data, it still gt inserted, I've 3 field, says it's id, name, and address.. they gt inserted as long as I run the query.

Comment: please update your question showing exactly the queries you run.

Comment: If you have `ID` as PRIMARY key, it will not add queries with same IDs. You can also set `UNIQUE` to `name` and/or `address` columns if you want to prevent duplication there.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/52268/discussion-between-user3522457-and-edvinas-me)